# how can I group my call backs in Rails

Tags: callback, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have many callbacks and I want to simplify or clean up the code.

Example:

```
  after_create :email_admin
  after_create  :update_author_resource_count
  after_create :get_resource_score
```

How can I write this like:

after_create :email_admin, :update_author_resource_count, :get_resource_score

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write this like

```
after_create :email_admin, :update_author_resource_count, :get_resource_score
```